# Silex and Symfony Security not letting me have anonymous routes

Tags: php, symfony, silex

I am building a site in Silex and using the Symfony Security component to secure the app.  There needs to be a route that is open to trigger events run by the cron, but this route keeps requiring me to login, even though I have set it up in the firewall not to.  Any help here would be appreciated.

```
$app['security.firewalls'] = array(
'login' => array(
    'pattern' => '^/user/login$',
),
'register' => array(
    'pattern' => '^/user/register$',
),
'cron' => array(
    'pattern' => '^/cron$',
),
'secured_area' => array(
    'pattern' => '^.*$',
    'anonymous' => false,
    'remember_me' => array(),
    'form' => array(
        'login_path' => '/user/login',
        'check_path' => '/user/login_check',
    ),
    'logout' => array(
        'logout_path' => '/user/logout',
    ),
    'users' => $app->share(function($app) { return $app['user.manager']; }),
  ),
);
```

Comment: You should enable monolog provider and see what firewall gets hit by /cron as @YassineGuedidi suggested disabling the security flag should do the trick. When log is enabled, the security component throws lots of debugging information that may help solve the issue. Can you post the copy of the log when requesting a resource in the /cron/ namespace?

Answer (score 0):

You can disable security for that firewall:

```
'cron' => array(
    'pattern' => '^/cron$',
    'security' => false,
),
```

Answer (score 0):

Try settings anonymous = true for the cron route